# Is it possible to generate wallet in the waves blockchain network with api node.js?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, wavesplatform

I need to generate wallet in blockchain waves for my project. Can I use some Node.js API for this?

Comment: It depends what you need but quick search gives this [`Node.js` repo](https://github.com/wavesplatform/waves-transactions). Does it work?

Comment: This works, but only for transactions. I needed to create wallets. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Take a look into their [Github repo](https://github.com/wavesplatform)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [waves-transactions](https://github.com/wavesplatform/waves-transactions) lib for nodejs/javascript it allow wallet (seed, address and keypair) creation as follow:

```
const wavesTransaction  = require('@waves/waves-transactions')
const seed = wavesTransaction.seedUtils.Seed.create();
console.log(seed.phrase)
console.log(seed.address)
console.log(seed.keyPair)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at [POST/addresses](https://nodes.wavesplatform.com/api-docs/index.html#!/addresses/create_1) node’s API method. This method will create a new address on your node.

Also, it’s possible to create a new seed phrase and then a private, public keys and an address using various [libraries](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/client-libraries.html) or you can use [Waves keeper](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-keeper/about-waves-keeper.html) as well.